# Using ReactJS with PHP

Tags: php, json, reactjs, axios

I ask for help on how to interact with ReactJS and PHP.

I have a php file to communicate with the database and get the data from the database in JSON format.

---

db.php

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-blog-header.php');

global $post;

$args = array(
   'numberposts' => '10',
   'offset' => '27',
   'post_type' => 'product',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'orderby' => 'menu_order',
   'order' => 'ASC'
);

$products = get_posts($args);

foreach ( $products as $product ) {
   $result = $products;
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

All is well and I get this in JSON format.

Using axios, I'm processing this PHP file in ReactJS.

---

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import axios from "axios";


import Product from "./Product";


componentWillMount() {

axios.get('db.php')
.then(({ data }) => {
     this.setState({
         result: data
         });
     });
}

render() {
    return(
        <div className="products">
            {this.state.result.map((product, i) => (
                <Product
                    key={i}
                    title={product.post_title}
                    guid={product.post_guid}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

---

Product.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Product = ({post_title, guid}) => (
    <div>
        <div>{post_title}</div>
        <div>{guid}</div>
    </div>
);

export default Product;
```

---

My JSON encode

```
[  
   {  
      "ID":3431,
 "post_title":"\u041a\u041e\u041d\u0426\u0415\u041d\u0422\u0420\u0410\u0422\u041e\u0420 8\u0424-1\/2",
      "guid":"http:\/\/domain.ru\/product\/koncentrator-8f-1-buk\/",
   },
]
```

And I get an error in ReactJS
The requested resource does not have the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".

In the hosts file already registered 127.0.0.1 localhost domain.com
But still a mistake.

How can I solve this problem or what to write in the axios query. Help me please! Thank you

Comment: What is the URL of the request that you're getting the error for?

Comment: I'm referring to the url http://example.com/db.php it is on the same server. but in a different directory. I tried already to specify the proxy in package.json, add headers to php. Nothing helps!

Comment: Please add the lines from this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25661403/933575 to `db.php`, and post back the results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set header for allow access control and pass headers in axios. also you need to enable cors on your php server.

Example of [cors implementation in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers).